# Ionic run android failed

Tags: android, android-studio, ionic-framework, ionic2

i'm trying to export my app and i run ionic run android and it failed.

that's the error

```
    C:\Users\adirz\myapps\sceSchedule>ionic run android

Running 'run:before' npm script before run
> ionic-hello-world@ build C:\Users\adirz\myapps\sceSchedule
> ionic-app-scripts build
[02:17:30]  ionic-app-scripts 0.0.41
[02:17:30]  build prod started ...
[02:17:30]  clean started ...
[02:17:30]  clean finished in 5 ms
[02:17:30]  copy started ...
[02:17:30]  ngc started ...
[02:17:31]  copy finished in 196 ms
[02:17:31]  lint started ...
[02:17:32]  tslint: C:/Users/adirz/myapps/sceSchedule/src/pages/courses-page/courses-page.ts, line: 5

            Unused import: 'course'
       L4:  import {CoursesData} from "../../providers/courses-data";
       L5:  import {course} from "../../models/Course";
[02:17:32]  tslint: C:/Users/adirz/myapps/sceSchedule/src/pages/tabs/tabs.ts, line: 3

            Unused import: 'HomePage'
       L3:  import { HomePage } from '../home/home';
       L4:  import { AboutPage } from '../about/about';
[02:17:32]  lint finished in 1.50 s
[02:17:43]  Error: Error at C:/Users/adirz/myapps/sceSchedule/.tmp/pages/courses-page/courses-page.ngfactory.ts:736:29

[02:17:43]  Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
[02:17:43]  Error at C:/Users/adirz/myapps/sceSchedule/.tmp/pages/courses-page/courses-page.ngfactory.ts:761:29
[02:17:43]  Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

[02:17:43]  ngc failed

[02:17:43]  ionic-app-script task: "build"

[02:17:43]  Error: Error
```

this is my course-page.ts

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {NavController, LoadingController,AlertController} from 'ionic-angular';

import {CoursesData} from "../../providers/courses-data";
import {course} from "../../models/Course";

/*
  Generated class for the CoursesPage page.

  See http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#navigation for more info on
  Ionic pages and navigation.
*/
@Component({
  selector: 'page-courses-page',
  templateUrl: 'courses-page.html'
})
export class CoursesPage {
  public semester: string = 'SemA';
 // public coursesA: Array<any> = [];
  public coursesB: Array<any> = [];
  public coursesC:Array<any>=[];
  public department:any;
  public courseSelect: string = '';
  public lectureSelect:string= '';
  public coursesNames:Array<any>=[];
  public LecturesNames:Array<any>=[];
  public LectureCourses:Array<any>=[];
  public loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
    content: "Please wait...",
    spinner: 'crescent'

  });
  public data=null;
  public coursesA:Array<any>=[];
    public coursesAD:Array<any>=[];
  public coursesChose:Array<any>=[];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,private loadingCtrl: LoadingController,public coursesData:CoursesData,public alertCtrl: AlertController) {

  }


  ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.loader.present();
      this.onSemChange(); 
    }
    public getCourses(semester:any){
      this.courseSelect='';
      this.coursesNames=[];
      this.LecturesNames=[];
      this.coursesA=[];
      console.log(semester);
     this.coursesData.LoadData(semester)
        .subscribe(courseList=> {
          courseList.forEach(course=>{
          var newCourse={
               id_course:course.id_course ,
              key_course:course.key_course,
              course_name:course.course_name ,
              course_type:course.course_type ,
              start:course.start ,
              end:course.end ,
              point_course:course.point_course ,
              day:course.Day,
              class:course.class,
              lecture_name:course.lecture_name
          }
            this.coursesA.push(newCourse);
            this.coursesNames.push(course.course_name);
            this.LecturesNames.push(course.lecture_name);
          });
          //this.courseSelect=this.coursesNames[0];
          this.coursesAD=this.coursesA;
          this.coursesNames = this.coursesNames.filter(function(elem, index, self) {
                  return index == self.indexOf(elem);
              })
              console.log(this.coursesA);


               this.loader.dismiss();
               console.log(this.coursesNames);
        // return this.coursesA;

        },err=>{
          console.log(err);
        });
  }



  public onCourseChange(){
    console.log(this.courseSelect);
    this.coursesA=this.coursesAD;
    //getCourses();
  this.coursesChose=[];
  this.LecturesNames=[];
   for (let course of this.coursesA) {
      if (course.course_name==this.courseSelect){
        this.coursesChose.push(course);
        this.LecturesNames.push(course.lecture_name);
        console.log(this.LecturesNames);
      }       
  }
    this.coursesA = this.coursesChose; 
  this.LecturesNames = this.LecturesNames.filter(function(elem, index, self) {
                  return index == self.indexOf(elem);
              })
  console.log(this.LecturesNames);
  console.log(this.coursesChose);
  }

  public onLectureChange(){
      this.coursesA=this.coursesAD;
    //getCourses();
  this.LectureCourses=[];
    for (let course of this.coursesA) {
      if (course.lecture_name==this.lectureSelect){
        this.LectureCourses.push(course);
      }
         this.coursesA = this.LectureCourses;
  }
  }
  public addDep(){}
  public onSemChange(){
   let semester=JSON.stringify({'semester':this.semester});
   console.log(semester);
   this.getCourses(semester);

  }
}
```

i deleted the tmp folder it says there and still i have the issue.
i tried to close the program and restart again and still i have the same issue

the tmp folder

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {NavController, LoadingController,AlertController} from 'ionic-angular';

import {CoursesData} from "../../providers/courses-data";
import {course} from "../../models/Course";

/*
  Generated class for the CoursesPage page.

  See http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#navigation for more info on
  Ionic pages and navigation.
*/
@Component({
  selector: 'page-courses-page',
  templateUrl: 'courses-page.html'
})
export class CoursesPage {
  public semester: string = 'SemA';
 // public coursesA: Array<any> = [];
  public coursesB: Array<any> = [];
  public coursesC:Array<any>=[];
  public department:any;
  public courseSelect: string = '';
  public lectureSelect:string= '';
  public coursesNames:Array<any>=[];
  public LecturesNames:Array<any>=[];
  public LectureCourses:Array<any>=[];
  public loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
    content: "Please wait...",
    spinner: 'crescent'

  });
  public coursesA:Array<any>=[];
   public coursesAD:Array<any>=[];
  public coursesChose:Array<any>=[];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,private loadingCtrl: LoadingController,public coursesData:CoursesData,public alertCtrl: AlertController) {

  }


  ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.loader.present();
      this.onSemChange(); 
    }
    public getCourses(semester:any){
      this.courseSelect='';
      this.coursesNames=[];
      this.LecturesNames=[];
      this.coursesA=[];
      console.log(semester);
     this.coursesData.LoadData(semester)
        .subscribe(courseList=> {
          courseList.forEach(course=>{
          var newCourse={
               id_course:course.id_course ,
              key_course:course.key_course,
              course_name:course.course_name ,
              course_type:course.course_type ,
              start:course.start ,
              end:course.end ,
              point_course:course.point_course ,
              day:course.Day,
              class:course.class,
              lecture_name:course.lecture_name
          }
            this.coursesA.push(newCourse);
            this.coursesNames.push(course.course_name);
            this.LecturesNames.push(course.lecture_name);
          });
          //this.courseSelect=this.coursesNames[0];
          this.coursesAD=this.coursesA;
          this.coursesNames = this.coursesNames.filter(function(elem, index, self) {
                  return index == self.indexOf(elem);
              })
              console.log(this.coursesA);


               this.loader.dismiss();
               console.log(this.coursesNames);
        // return this.coursesA;

        },err=>{
          console.log(err);
        });
  }



  public onCourseChange(){
    console.log(this.courseSelect);
    this.coursesA=this.coursesAD;
    //getCourses();
  this.coursesChose=[];
  this.LecturesNames=[];
   for (let course of this.coursesA) {
      if (course.course_name==this.courseSelect){
        this.coursesChose.push(course);
        this.LecturesNames.push(course.lecture_name);
        console.log(this.LecturesNames);
      }       
  }
    this.coursesA = this.coursesChose; 
  this.LecturesNames = this.LecturesNames.filter(function(elem, index, self) {
                  return index == self.indexOf(elem);
              })
  console.log(this.LecturesNames);
  console.log(this.coursesChose);
  }

  public onLectureChange(){
      this.coursesA=this.coursesAD;
    //getCourses();
  this.LectureCourses=[];
    for (let course of this.coursesA) {
      if (course.lecture_name==this.lectureSelect){
        this.LectureCourses.push(course);
      }
         this.coursesA = this.LectureCourses;
  }
  }
  public addDep(){}
  public onSemChange(){
   let semester=JSON.stringify({'semester':this.semester});
   console.log(semester);
   this.getCourses(semester);

  }
}
```

line 761:29 i don't really have but line 29 i have

```
line public loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
    content: "Please wait...",
    spinner: 'crescent'

  });
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant lines from `/.tmp/pages/courses-page/courses-page.ngfactory.ts:736:29`?

Comment: sure. i don't have 736 but i added my post and you can see what i put

Comment: 736:29 means that the error is on line 736, character 29. But the error is not in your courses-page.ts, its in the courses-page.ngfactory.ts. This file is created by the angular 2 compiler and seems to have an error in it. It would help if you could show us the relevant lines from that generated file.

Comment: By the way, the .tmp folder will only be created if you remove the --dev flag again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a temporary solution you can edit your `package.json` file and add the `--dev` flag to the build step. This will turn off the AoT compiler and you can continue working on your app.

Replace

`"build": "ionic-app-scripts build"`

with

`"build": "ionic-app-scripts build --dev"`

Comment: thank you! it works!!!!! but it's the best way? you said it's temporary solution.

Comment: Yes, this is only a temporary solution. When you build your app, the angular 2 compiler optimizes your code so it runs faster. The compiler will sometimes find additional errors that you don't see when using `ionic serve` for example. So you should only use the --dev flag until you found the cause for that error.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `addDep` in your **courses-page** since error says that **addDep** is missing.

```
  [20:33:25] Property 'addDep' does not exist on type 'CoursesPage'.
    [20:33:25] Error at C:/Users/adirz/myapps/sceSchedule/.tmp/pages/courses-page/courses-page.ngfactory.ts:889:42
    [20:33:25] Property 'addDep' does not exist on type 'CoursesPage'.
```

Comment: can you check my post again? it failed again